# Limit of Viète's sequence

Tags: trigonometry

I have to calculate the limit of $V_n / 2^n$.

Here is
$V_n=\prod \:\:_{k=1}^{n\:}\left(2\cos\left(\frac{\pi \:}{2^{k+1}}\right)\right)$

On the answer sheet of my exercise, the answer of $\lim _{n\to \:\infty }\left(\frac{V_n}{2^n}\right)$ is $\frac{2}{\pi }$

Here's what I've done:
$V_n=2^n\cdot \prod \:\:\:_{k=1}^{n\:}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi \:\:}{2^{k+1}}\right)\right)$

Because $\sin\left(2x\right)=2\cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)$ we have:

$\cos\left(\frac{\pi \:\:\:}{2^{n+1}}\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2^k}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi \:}{2^{k+1}}\right)}$

resulting in

$V_n=2^n\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\cdot \:\prod \:\:\:\:_{k=1}^{n\:}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi \:}{2^k}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi \:\:}{2^{k+1}}\right)}\right)$

$V_n=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2^{n+1}}\right)}$

$V_n=\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2^{n+1}}\right)}$

$V_n=\frac{\frac{\pi \:\:}{2^{n+1}}}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi \:}{2^{n+1}}\right)}\cdot \frac{2^{n+1}}{\pi }$

$\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2^{n+1}}\right)}{\frac{\pi \:}{2^{n+1}}}\right)=1\:\:$

EDIT: corrected error, thus getting the correct result. Question solved

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly *will* lead you to the answer on the sheet! Great job getting this far!

Do you know that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1?$$

What happens if you let $x = \pi/2^n$ and take $n \to \infty$?